# Bottom Menu does not stretched/bind properly when the orientation changes

Tags: codenameone

I'm having the issue with Bottom Menu not stretched according to the space available when the device change the orientation from portrait to landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `autoAdjust` and essentially reshow the dialog on orientation change:

```
protected void autoAdjust(int w, int h) {
    dispose();
    showStretched(BorderLayout.SOUTH, false);
}
```